# How to load products from a specific category based on special price availability?

Tags: magento-1

I have following code

```
$promoCatId = (int)Mage::getStoreConfig('promoprodsec/promoprodgroup/promocategoryid');

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId($store)->load($promoCatId)
    ->getProductCollection();
$allProductsInPromoCategory = $products->getAllIds();
```

It gives me all the products of $promoCatId category.

Now I want to get all the products which are not having special price or the special price date range has expired from all the products of  `$allProductsInPromoCategory`

How can I accomplish this without using foreach loop and again loading every product collection again?

```
foreach ($allProductsInPromoCategory as $promoprod) {
    Mage:getModel('catalog/product')->load( $promoprod);

    //do validation for the special price criteria
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Magento - Show Only Special Priced Products In A Category](http://www.creativemgroup.com/creative-media-web-services/magento-blog/27-magento-show-only-special-priced-products-in-a-category)

```
    $todayDate = strftime("%Y-%m-%d",Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeTimeStamp(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()));
    $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();  
    $product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');  

    //To Do - load category here
    $product->addCategoryFilter($category)

    $this->_productCollection = $product->setStoreId($storeId)  
      ->getCollection()  
      ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','status', 'price', 'special_price', 'small_image','required_options','special_from_date', 'special_to_date'), 'inner')
                ->joinField('stock_status','cataloginventory/stock_status','stock_status',
                    'product_id=entity_id', array(
                      'stock_status' => Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Status::STATUS_IN_STOCK,
                      'website_id' => Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId(),
                    ))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('gt' => 0), 'left')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                    0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
                    1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
                ), 'left')
                //->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
                ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
                ->addFinalPrice()
                ->addStoreFilter()
                ->setPageSize($this->getProductsLimit())
                ->setCurPage($page)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                ->addUrlRewrite();

            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);  
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);


      $checkedProducts = new Varien_Data_Collection();
      foreach ($this->_productCollection as $k => $p) {
          $p = $p->loadParentProductIds();
          $parentIds = $p->getData('parent_product_ids');

          if (is_array($parentIds) && !empty($parentIds)) {
              if (!$checkedProducts->getItemById($parentIds[0])) {
                  $parentProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($parentIds[0]);
                  if ($parentProduct->isVisibleInCatalog()) {
                      $checkedProducts->addItem($parentProduct);
                  }
              }
          } else {
              if (!$checkedProducts->getItemById($k)) {
                  $checkedProducts->addItem($p);
              }
          }
          if (count($checkedProducts) >= $this->getProductsLimit()) {
              break;
          }
      }

      return $this->_productCollection;
```